# How to collapse the leaflet control

Tags: leaflet

I start my application with expand Layer-Control:

```
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays, { collapsed:false } ).addTo(mymap);
```

I found no Mouse-Action to minimize the Layer-Control. I want to minimize the Layer-Control. But I don't know the handler. Could anybody give me a tip?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement for Leaflet.  I needed to have the layer control expanded at first and then return to its normal hiding after someone realizes what it does.

I am using JQuery, but you could probably manipulate the DOM as well.

I have a function that instantiates the layer control object, and then I immediately reset the mouseenter and mouseleave events for the expanded control and the smaller toggle widget.

```
let layerControl = L.control.layers(basemap_items, { 'specialLayer': layer}, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
$('.leaflet-control-layers').on('mouseleave', () => {
    layerControl.collapse();
});
$('.leaflet-control-layers-toggle').on('mouseenter', () => {
    layerControl.expand();
});
```